# Export R Dataframe to Excel Workbook

Tags: r, openxlsx

I want to save my dataframe in an excel workbook. The wb_add_list function add subheaders to the dataframes and the for loop runs runs for multiple input values. For each input value, the table should be saved in a sheet with the same name and all the column except the first one should be centered.

This is what I have been working on:

```
 wb_add_list <- function(wb, x) {
    wb <- wb$clone()
    row <- 1
    # Get column names of the input data
    col_names <- colnames(x[[1]])
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      # Add the original table headers only at the first row of the whole table
      if (i == 1) {
        wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = t(col_names), colNames = FALSE)
        # wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:length(col_names))
        dims <- paste0("A", row,":D", row)
        wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("#8EA9DB")) # Light blue color
        wb$add_font(dims = dims, color = wb_color("white"))
        row <- row + 1L
      }
      wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = names(x[i]), colNames = FALSE)
      wb$merge_cells(rows = row, cols = 1:length(col_names))
      dims <- paste0("A", row)
      # Set the color of the header created by the Group column to #E7E6E6
      if (grepl(" ", names(x[i]))) {
        wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("#E7E6E6"))
      } else {
        wb$add_fill(dims = dims, color = wb_color("white"))
      }
      row <- row + 1L
      wb$add_data(startRow = row, x = x[[i]], colNames = FALSE)
      row <- row + nrow(x[[i]])
    }
    wb
  } 
  
  # create a new Excel workbook
  wb <- wb_workbook()
  
  for (i in seq_along(input_values)) {
    # use the write_to_excel function to generate the data frame for the current input value
    df <- write_to_excel(input_values[i])
    
    # add a new worksheet to the workbook for the current input value with the specified sheet name
    wb <- wb$add_worksheet(name = input_values[i])
    
    # format the Group column
    df$Group <- paste0(" ", df$Group)
    out <- split(df[-5], f = df$Group)
    
    wb_add_list(wb, out)
  }
  
  # Save the Excel file
  wb_save(wb, "result.xlsx")
```

This only saves the output, but the sheet does not take the name of the input value and the data is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be what you are looking for (you cannot simply invent functions)

```r
library(openxlsx2)
input_values <- list(iris = iris, mtcars = mtcars)

# create a new Excel workbook
wb <- wb_workbook()

for (i in seq_along(input_values)) {
  # use the write_to_excel function to generate the data frame for the current input value
  wb$add_worksheet(names(input_values)[i])
  
  # add a new worksheet to the workbook for the current input value with the specified sheet name
  wb <- wb$add_data(x = input_values[[i]])
  
  # one possible way to create dimensions
  dims <- attr(wb_data(wb), "dims")
  dims_to_center <- dataframe_to_dims(dims[-1])
  
  # center the column horizontaly
  wb$add_cell_style(dims = dims_to_center, horizontal = "center")

}

# wb$open()
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "you cannot simply invent functions"? You certainly can create user-defined functions in R, so I am unclear on what you mean by this phrase